# Feature Labels Disappear at Lower Zoom Levels, I want to force them to always appear

Tags: openlayers-3

What controls whether or not a feature label will display? I would like to force the feature labels to display regardless of zoom level and relative distance to another feature.  There is some magic happening behind the scenes that makes the labels disappear as zoom level decreases (panning out).  Is there a way to override this?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html

I thought the declutter option could be set to false, but that didn't do it either:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-label-decluttering.html

Comment: set `overflow` in the text style https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html  It was called exceedLength before version 4.6 (it's still confusingly called that in the example you linked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike found the answer.  In ol.style.Text, set the option (overflow:true).